# Call performclick() from another form without make an instance of it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have an static var in my application and if this var is true i want to perform a click in another form but how can i do this in a clean way without make an instance of that form like this:

```
private  MainForm _main
```

I just want to do performClick on that button without make an instance of that form.

EDIT:

```
Edit_Customer mainFormChild = new Edit_Customer();
formList.Add(mainFormChild);
mainFormChild.Show();
```

Comment: Show us some more code please, and clarify what button are you talking about and what is meant by "make an instance of that method"

Comment: i meant form, sorry. It's just a button called button_ReloadData.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two forms.  Is this form created by that other form, essentially treated as a "sub form" of it, like a popup, is the relationship reversed, or what?

Comment: The Form is an form to edit customers and it is created by that Form. I've added some code to show how the form is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That form should have an `event` that it fires when it would like the main form to do something.

```
public class Edit_Customer
{
    public event Action SomethingHappened;//TODO give meaningful name
}
```

Fire that event at the appropriate time.

The main form can then add a handler to that event when creating the form, within which it can do whatever it wants:

```
Edit_Customer mainFormChild = new Edit_Customer();
mainFormChild.SomethingHappened += () => DoSomething();
mainFormChild.Show();
```

Comment: it does not work for me. I get the error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and await "new object" expressions can be used as an instruction. and: "System.Action 'is a' type 'but is used like a' variable' and ; expected. I've added how i did it to my post above.

Comment: @user3438236 You can copy-paste this code into a blank project and it will compile just fine.  You must be doing something other than what is shown here.

Comment: i don't know what was wrong but know it's working. It's easier than i thought, thanks. How can i fire that event now? Like this: SomethingHappened() right?

Comment: Could i also add two methods to this or do i need a second event for that?

Comment: @user3438236 You would need a second event if the handlers attached to them need to happen at different times.  If you want to do multiple thing anytime Something Happens then just attach multiple handlers to the same event.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. But what about this => What does it mean? Is that Linq?

Comment: @user3438236 No, it's not LINQ.  It's a lambada; it is defining an anonymous method.